# Why can't I see background image?

Tags: html, css

I want to add image to section but it doesn't show.

This is my CSS part of that section:

```
#start{
  height: 100vh;
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
}

.start-img{
  background-image: url("assets/img/bg.png");
  display:block;

}

.section{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And this is HTML:

```
<section id="start">
  <div class="strt-img">

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Other than height, you just need to make sure your html class matches css `.start-img` vs `strt-img`

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that typo but its not that. Tried adding content or adding height but still cant see image.

Comment: Check the image URL then, that's probably it. If you inspect the div you should be able to see if that image url is working or not

Comment: Probably easier to set a url starting with `/`

Comment: I used this now (../../assets/img/bg.png). Because my styles are in assets/css/styles.css and my image is in assets/img/bg.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `height`, since it does not have any content.
Try adding, for example: `height: 100px;`.

Or, if you want this to fill the section background, apply `position: relative;` to the sections, and then use:

```
.strt-img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

this will strech it to the section's width and height.

**UPDATE:**

```css
#start {
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.start-img {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500");
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="start">
    <div class="start-img">

    </div>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7tn56hg/1/)

Comment: Tnx for helping but it didn't do anything. Also I fixed typo strt-img to start-img, so its not that either.

Comment: Please check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7tn56hg/1/) I added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height to your `.strt-img` div.

Since there is no content in that element, it's fully collapsed. If you add a paragraph or anything to that div, you'll see your background image.